# calling a function placed in another

Tags: python, jquery, css, forms, menu

I have a problem calling a function placed in another.
I have to call [selectItem (frame)] from [Display_Recette (Name_HV)]

```
def SAF_Contenu(root):
     def selectItem(frame):   
def Display_Recette(Name_HV):
     F_TOP_Treeview_ID.bind('<<Declenche>>', selectItem(iid))
```

Comment: Assuming selectItem() had a return value, you could indent Display_Recette() to become an inner function and call it that way.

Comment: What you are trying to do is call a private method (selectItem(), which only its parent SAF_Contenu() can call) by an outside method (Display_Recette()).

Answer (score 0):

you can make the inner function `global`

```
def fnA(a,b):
    global fnB
    def fnB(c,d):
        return c+d
    return a*b
print(fnA(1,2))
print(fnB(1,2))
```

```
2
3
```